# Keyboard locks in IntelliJ IDEA based editors on Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Multiple times a day keyboard stops responding in IDEA based products.

If I quickly cmd-tab to another application and back again, it will work again.

It's occurring so often that it's starting to really annoy me. This affects all the Idea based editors I'm using, which are:

PhpStorm, AppCode, Android Studio, PyCharm, IDEA 15.

I notice it often happens when auto completion popup appears. But it also happens without the completion popup.

I've used IDEA products on 3 different macs, and I've seen the problem on all.

Comment: With this kind of issues you better contact JetBrains support directly -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Answer (score 0):

please follow  [IDEA-132221](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132221) and [IDEA-122525](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122525) for updates